# Compact and self-adjoint operator in $L^2$, and its eigenvalues

Tags: real-analysis, compact-operators, self-adjoint-operators

Let $K:L^2([-\pi,\pi])\rightarrow L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ the operator defined as
\begin{align*}
(Kf)(t)=\int_\pi^\pi\vert t-s\vert f(s)\,\mathrm{d}s.
\end{align*}
I proved that $K$ is self-adjoint and how can I prove that $K$ is compact? How do I find its eigenvalues?

Comment: Usually you use Arzela-Ascoli for these types of questions. To find the eigenvalues, start with finding the spectrum. Note that the spectrum is definitely real-valued since your operator is self-adjoint.

Comment: Do you have some assumptions on $f$ which you are ommiting?

Comment: No, no further assumptions on $f$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First part: K is compact**

For that, you want to show that the image of the unite ball of $L^2$ is pre-compact, that is its adherence is compact.
You can use the Arzela-Ascoli theorem. You will verify that all the function in the image are bound by the same value,which can be done by a Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. Then you have to show that function in the image are equicontinous. This can be done easily as we are on a compact and notice that $Kf$ is always a continous function.

---

**Finding the eigenvalues**

As said before $Kf$ is continuous. More specifficaly if $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^k$, $Kf$ is $\mathcal{C}^{k+1}$. We have that if $Kf =\lambda f$ then $f \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}$.

You can now differentiate to find a differential equation. If my calculus are correct, you find:

> $ 2f = \lambda f''$

Which we know the solutions:

> if $\lambda = 0$ then $f=0$, not a eigenvalue 
>  if $\lambda > 0$ then $f(t)=A e^{t/\tau}+B e^{-t/ \tau}$ with $\tau = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2}}$ 
>  if $0 > \lambda$ then $f(t)=A cos(\omega t)+B sin(\omega t)$ with $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{-2}{\lambda}}$

Then one need to verify that this solution work. If we note $F$ a primitive of $f$ and $G$  a primitive of $F$ we can show by integrating by part that $Kf$ can be written

> $Kf(t)=2G(t) + (F(\pi)+F(\pi))(\pi-t)-(G(\pi)+G(-\pi)) $

So we need

> $(F(\pi)+F(\pi))(\pi-t)-(G(\pi)+G(-\pi))=0$ this does not happen if $\lambda > 0$ and otherwise gives $2 cos (\omega t)=0$

This give the eigenvalues

> $\lambda = \frac{-1}{2(1/2 +k )^2 } $ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I really thank you, because I was trying some exercises for a PhD's entrance exam but we never did such things in our courses. Really thank you!